# Should I not call gen_server:stop() directly?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

In the [LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers) book the author handles the termination of the server as follows:

```
%% Synchronous call
close_shop(Pid) -> gen_server:call(Pid, terminate).

handle_call(terminate, _From, Cats) ->
    {stop, normal, ok, Cats}.

terminate(normal, Cats) ->
    [io:format("~p was set free.~n",[C#cat.name]) || C <- Cats],
    ok.
```

So it returns a `stop` value from the `handle_call` callback.

Here is how I wrote it:

```
close_shop(Pid) -> gen_server:stop(Pid).

terminate(_Reason, {Cats, Money}) ->
    io:format("Made $~w~n", [Money]),
    [io:format("~p was set free.~n",[C#cat.name]) || C <- Cats].
```

Is this not a good practice then to call `gen_server:stop()` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bad practice to call `gen_server:stop/1,3` directly. It does an almost same thing as the example from LYSE but without calling `handle_call/3` from your module. Try and check it out. You can even read the source code to be sure.

Comment: Is it common practice to return "ok" from the terminate callback? Since the manual says that "The return value is ignored.".

Comment: @drozzy: You have to return something. Atom `ok` is as good as any other atom. It also already exists so it is a little bit better than returning `'my extra different atom just to be funny'` or making some complex term and allocating it on the heap.

Comment: @drozzy: There is newer nothing returned except when you raise an exception, error or exit. In your example, you return a list of `ok` atoms. (Same as `lists:duplicate(length(Cats), ok).`)